# Convergence of idempotents preserve dimension of range

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Suppose that $H$ is a Hilbert space and that $\{P_n\}_n$ is a sequence of bounded idempotents such that $\|P_n-P\|\rightarrow 0$ (where $P$ is another bounded idempotent, however I guess this follows from convergence). **Does it then hold that $\dim\mathrm{ran}~P_n\rightarrow \dim\mathrm{ran}~P$?** With this I mean: does there exist some $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n\geq N$ implies that $\dim \mathrm{ran}~P_n =\dim \mathrm{ran}~P$ in the sense of cardinals?

Here $\mathrm{ran}$ denotes the range of the operator.

For orthogonal projections this is true (see for instance Theorem 4.35 in *Linear Operators in Hilbert Spaces* by J. Weidmann) so adding the condition that all operators are self-adjoint would imply the convergence however what I wonder is if this holds also for bounded idempotents.

Comment: Are each $P_n$ finite rank?

Comment: Not necessarily but does it hold in that case?

Comment: It's more that I'm not sure how to parse $\dim \operatorname{ran} P_n$ otherwise.

Comment: Dimension of a basis of the pre-Hilbert space

Comment: So, if $P_n$ has infinite rank, are we then talking about infinite cardinals for $\dim \operatorname{ran} P_n$? In what sense will these infinite cardinals converge to $\dim \operatorname{ran} P$? Sorry if my set theory knowledge is too weak.

Comment: You are right normal limits do not make sense in that case. I added what I mean by convergence of the dimensions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can prove the following: if $P,Q\in B(H)$ are idempotents such that $\|P-Q\|<1$, then their ranges have the same dimension. Since from $P_n\to P$ we get that there exists an $n_0$ such that $\|P_n-P\|<1$ for all $n\geq n_0$, it follows that  $\dim\operatorname{ran}(P_n)=\dim\operatorname{ran}(P)$ for all $n\geq n_0$.

To prove it, let $x_1,\ldots,x_m\in PH$ be linearly independent. Suppose that $\sum_j\alpha_jQx_j=0$. Then 
$$
\|\sum_j\alpha_jx_j\|=\|\sum_j\alpha_jPx_j-\sum_j\alpha_jQx_j\|\leq\|P-Q\|\,\|\sum_j\alpha_jx_j\|. 
$$
Since $\|P-Q\|<1$, the strict inequality is impossible, so we conclude that $\sum_j\alpha x_j=0$, and then by linearly independence $\alpha_1=\ldots=\alpha_m=0$. Thus $Qx_1,\ldots,Qx_m$ are linearly independent.

The roles can be reversed, so for any linearly independent subset of $PH$ there is a linearly independent subset of $QH$ with the same cardinality. Thus $\dim PH=\dim QH$.

And, as a consequence, it follows that if $\|P-Q\|<1$ then $P$ and $Q$ are unitarily equivalent.